# Formula for sequences: $a_0=1,b_0=1,a_{n+1}=a_n+b_n,b_{n+1}=2a_n+b_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The following two sequences are given:

\begin{align}
a_0&=1 \\
b_0&=1 \\
a_{n+1}&=a_n+b_n \\
b_{n+1}&=2a_n+b_n
\end{align}

Is it possible to create a simple formula for $a_n$ and $b_n$? I played with the sequence, but i was not able to find a solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Subtracting the first recurrence from the second, we find that $b_{n+1}-a_{n+1}=a_n$, i.e., that $b_{n+1}=a_{n+1}+a_n$ and hence that $b_n=a_n+a_{n-1}$. Substituting this into the first recurrence yields the recurrence

$$a_{n+1}=2a_n+a_{n-1}\;.$$

This can be solved by any of the standard techniques. For example, the auxiliary equation is $x^2-2x-x=0$, with roots

$$x=\frac{2\pm\sqrt{8}}2=1\pm\sqrt{2}\;,$$

so the solution will have the form

$$a_n=c_0(1+\sqrt2)^n+c_1(1-\sqrt2)^n\;,$$

with constants $c_0,c_1$ determined from the initial values. And once you have $a_n$, the recurrence $b_{n+1}=a_{n+1}+a_n$ will give you $b_n$.

Comment: nice soltuion +1

Comment: very nice! thanks brian!

Answer (score 4):

Sure. The trick is to write the sequence in Matrix notation:
$$\begin{pmatrix}a_{n+1} \\ b_{n+1}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_n \\ b_n\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}^n\begin{pmatrix}a_0 \\ b_0\end{pmatrix},$$
now you only need to diagonalize the matrix to compute it's $n$-th power.